# Deploying A Node.JS server that uses mongoose to connect to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose, docker-swarm

i have created a server in Node.Js that uses Express to listen and create responses to requests. I am using mongoose for the MongoDB database to extract values.

How can i deploy it online? Should i dockerize the environment with everything and then use the Cloud Run from Google?

one more question i have is what do i set the database URL for the mongoose connection? For developing, i was using this: `DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost/toDoBeta` does that have to be changed?

as for the dockerfile, this is what i tried to put:

```
FROM node:19.9.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

although, i get an `error MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED`

I am not really sure what steps to take in order to launch this and help would be greatly appreciated :)